# cakephp pagination removing specific results

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I'm paginating some results within my cakephp 2.x install. They work fine with the following code:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'conditions' => array('not' => array('Listing.status_code' => '1')),
        'limit' => 20,
        );
```

But when I order the results:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'conditions' => array('not' => array('Listing.status_code' => '1')),
        'limit' => 20,
        'order' => array('Listing.created' => 'desc'),
        );
```

These two values: Listing.image, Listing.images_dir become empty in the array?!

The only difference between image and images_dir and the other values in the table could be to do with the Upload plugin used to save the values in the Model, but I don't see why this would cause a problem when retrieving the values. Removing Upload from $actsAs does not resolve the problem.

Any ideas where I should look to resolve this?

Comment: Try changing order to a string instead of an array:  'Listing.created desc'

Comment: @dave thanks, but nope, turning to a string has no affect on order.

Comment: Would help greatly if you showed both the before and after queries it generates.

Comment: try to on debug mode and share queries with and without ordering